# __declspec (thread) on arrays

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

The following code:

```
__declspec (thread) static int  somearray[4][4] = { 
  {16, 12, 12,  8},
  {12,  8,  8,  4},
  {12,  8,  8,  4},
  { 8,  4,  4,  0}};
```

throws the following error:

```
error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'
```

It seems that I'm not using threadlocal correctly with arrays here. How should I do it correclty?

Comment: No idea if VS2005 has a problem with that, doubtful even though it is *old*.  Look in the code before this, especially an #include.  It may well be missing a semi-colon.

Comment: Nah, I'm just retroactively putting that stuff into a badly written codebase that needs to be parallelized. The code compiled fine before.